# how to send html and text mail with python

Tags: python, smtp

I want the mail body containing html and text ,but either of them only shows up on mail body if i set the **MIMEMultipart('')** to **MIMEMultipart('alternative')** or **MIMEMultipart('mixed')** ,how to make them both on the mail body instead of html as attachment ?

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# me == my email address
# you == recipient's email address
me = "my@email.com"
you = "your@email.com"

msg = MIMEMultipart('')
msg['Subject'] = "Link"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = 'This is text'
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi!<br>
       How are you?<br>
       Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
# Send the message via local SMTP server.
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.live.com', 587)

mail.ehlo()

mail.starttls()

mail.login('userName', 'password')
mail.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
mail.quit()
```

Comment: Try this: `msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')`

Comment: @ RJ Adriaansen , it doesn't work .The mail shows me the html only not text and html.

Comment: `alternative` allows the e-mail client to choose to display either `html` or `text`

Comment: @RJ Adriaansen Thanks the the explanation. Seem it is no way to add html and text to message body.